# insert to table without detailing all columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to insert mysql table into php.
My members table includes columns: `id, name, email, birthday, mobile, sex, money, date_reg.`
I have the variables:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$sex = $_REQUEST['sex'];
$time = time();
```

I normally use the query:

```
mysqli($conn, "INSERT INTO members (name, email, sex, date_reg) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$sex', '$time');
```

But when I put up vps, I need to use the query:

```
mysqli($conn, "INSERT INTO members (name, email, birthday, mobile, money, sex, date_reg) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '','','' , '$time');
```

If the members table has too many columns then this insert becomes difficult. I still want to use the same query as the first query, there is a way I still do it.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this. If your PHP and mysql are running the same timezone you can use the current timestamp for the `date_reg` rather than `time()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a PHP issue. You have to set a default value for a mysql column in order to be able to ignore it during `INSERT`.

It's perfectly described in the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> A `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification explicitly indicates a default value for a column. Examples:
>
> `CREATE TABLE t1 (
>     i     INT DEFAULT -1,
>     c     VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '',
>     price DOUBLE(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00'
>   );`

Comment: I set the default value but can not insert into the table

Answer (score 0):

Problem like this is kinda subjective.

Try This

```
INSERT INTO table SET a=1, b=2, c=3
```

since it is easier to modify and easier to catch errors in the statement, especially when inserting lots of columns. If you have to insert 10 or 15 or more columns, it's really easy to mix something up using the (x, y) VALUES (1,2) syntax, in my opinion.

If portability between different SQL standards is an issue, then maybe `INSERT INTO table (x, y) VALUES (1,2)` would be preferred.

And if you want to insert multiple records in a single query, it doesn't seem like the `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax will work, whereas the other one will. But in most practical cases, you're looping through a set of records to do inserts anyhow, though there could be some cases where maybe constructing one large query to insert a bunch of rows into a table in one query, vs. a query for each row.

Comment: `This` is not really a useful answer. You should add a description for how this resolves the user issue(s).